# Setting default value of a calculated column to a user or group

Tags: 2007

How can I set the default value of a calculated column as a user / group name. Basically I want to create a view with that column included and where column name = [Me] so that if I/logged-in user is a part of group, I can see object in library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated columns don't have default values because they are derived from values existing in another field.  Person/group fields cannot have a default value so you'd have to have some script to populate it when the form is filled out.

I'd probably just create a view in the list with a filter where Created by equals [Me] and add additioanl filters that restrict data based on other columns to achive a similar result.[image: Creating a view filter]

Comment: But I want to fill the value of the custom column with a specific user/group. How do I do it? Only then I will create a view to filter contents.

Comment: Updated the answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Apart from Calculated Columns, is there any other type of column we can use..? Like the Person/Group column..?

Comment: Yes, you can use a person/Group column, but you need script to set the field value, it doesn't accomodate a default value.